# detect checkboxlist checked more than 1 item

Tags: c#

My checkboxlist contains 3 items A,B,C.
If user checks A which is what i want then user will obtain 2 marks
else user obtains 0 marks

My problem is that whenever user checks more than 3 item, user is still able obtain 2 marks, whereas by rights user should obtain zero marks because user checked A,B,C?

so how to make that if user has checked more than 1 box in checkboxlist then user will obtain 0 marks

example

```
if(A==A){
    //user obtain 2 marks
}else{
    //user obtain 0 marks
}

dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dtr.Read())
{
    if (dtr["Answer"].ToString() == CheckBoxList1.Text.ToString())
    {
        Label2.Text = "2 marks";
    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Text = "0 marks";
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("db not read");
}

dtr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i figured out the answer, thanks for help=) every checked the numSelected will increase by 1,once numSelected more then 2,user will get 0marks

```
int numSelected = 0;

foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        numSelected = numSelected + 1;
    }
}

Response.Write("Total Number Of CheckBoxes Selected:");

Response.Write(numSelected);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only ever want one selection to get marks then you should consider using a radio button instead of a checkbox. then you would only have to check

```
 if ( A == A) { //get marks }
```

Another thing you could do is to tag each checkbox with the value its worth

then when you check the results of all the check boxes you would award marks based on the checked tags?

```
 Checkbox b = new Checkbox();
 b.Tag = markValue;
```

Comment: aiks,so beside checkbox there are no way for checkboxlist to get what i want?

Comment: because i plan to use grid view to load checkboxlist for user to do online exercise

Comment: anyway, there are same problem with checkbox, once another checkbox is clicked , user still will obtain 2 marks

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the other boxes are un checked as well if you only want them to get the marks for only checking A

so something like

```
if(A==A && B!=B && C!=C){
   //get marks
} else {
   //no marks
}
```

Comment: ABC is just an example, how if my checkboxlist item more then 10? =x